# Blackberry Java replace char \n

Tags: string, blackberry, replace, java-me, split

I have an example string get from XML, contains: Hello\nWorld\n\nClick\nHere.\nThanks.
And then i want to replace the \n char with space char.
Already try using string replace, string substring, string indexOf. But cannot detect the \n char, iam trying using '\r\n' to detect, but didnt work.

```
String hello = "Hello\nWorld\n\nClick\nHere.\nThanks.";
String afterReplace = hello.replace('\n', ' ');
```

But still cannot remove/replace the \n with space.
Anyone can help me?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: That works fine. Is that your original text?

Comment: Your code works just fine.

Comment: Do you want to replace the new-line char '\n' or do you want to replace the string "\n" which would have to be escaped in code as "\\n"?

Comment: maybe you want replaceAll? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

Comment: Beware: `replace` takes a char/CharSequence whereas `replaceAll` takes a regex and needs to escape.

Comment: replaceall() is not available in BlackBerry Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you have a string which when printed shows the \n characters and does not actually skip a line.

Hello\nWorld\n\nClick\nHere.\nThanks. would be represented in code by:

```
String s = "Hello\\nWorld\\n\\nClick\\nHere.\\nThanks."
```

Now s is equal to what you would obtain from your XML.

Try this:

```
String afterReplace = hello.replace('\\n', ' ');
```

Comment: Solved! Thanks,i am using String afterReplace = replace(Hello, "\\n", "");